# C++ array returns incorrect number

Tags: c++, arrays, output

My code is a program that lets the user enter ten numbers into an array and then the program displays the largest and smallest numbers that were entered. The code I have works great for the smallest number but it displays "4254729" for the largest number every time I run it.

I have been working on it since yesterday, switching things around and trying different inputs, nothing has worked.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //defining my variables
    int numbers[10];
    int smallest = 0;
    int largest = 0;
    int temporary = 0;

    //beginning of my for loop to let the user enter numbers into the array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter number " << i+1 << " : "<< endl << endl;
        cin >> numbers[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    //assining the smallest and largest numbers to the first numbers in the array
    smallest = numbers[0];
    largest = numbers[0];

    //beginning of for loop to compare the numbers entered
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        temporary = numbers[i];
        if (temporary > largest)
            largest = temporary;

        if(temporary < smallest)
            smallest = temporary;
    }

    //cout statements to display the largest and smallest numbers entered
    cout << "The largest number entered is: " << largest << endl << endl;
    cout << "The smallest number entered is: " << smallest << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the largest number displayed to reflect the largest number that the user enters but displays "4254729" as the largest number every time I run the program.

Comment: Change `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)` to `for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: Red flag alarm: `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`

Comment: Array indices start at *`0`*, *not* `1`.

Comment: @dedecos That fixed my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi would be better if you add your inputs in the question, but i fix some stuff, maybe will work.

```
//beginning of for loop to compare the numbers entered
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) //I change i<=10 to <
{
    temporary = numbers[i];
    if (temporary > largest)
        largest = temporary;

    else if (temporary < smallest) //Here I put else
        smallest = temporary;
}
```

Comment: It works? If yes,pls accept,.

Comment: I believe that the `for` should be: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`, since array indices start at 0.  The statement: `for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)` will actually iterate 9 times, not 10.

Comment: its not necessary start i=0, bc already do it before the for loop.The mistake was you i<=10 (i=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and the max index is 9(10 index dont exist in array), so i<10. @ThomasMatthews